# Excel document's layout changes when printer is changed

Tags: excel, pdf, printing, printers, pdf-conversion

I have an excel document and was trying to convert this into PDF. But the radio buttons in that excel sheet is getting enlarged while converting into PDF. I checked the print preview and observed the same, but *when I changed the default printer this got fixed*, the radio buttons was behaving as expected, The margins was also proper. Can anyone help me in finding out how printer is associated with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since the relevant code is closed-source, I don't see how your question can be answered. File a bug report with Microsoft if it bothers you, but you seem to have found a work around, so why worry?

Comment: @JohnColeman customers use to export data into pdf from  my tool. as we don't know which printers they are using. and this is causing issues like radio button enlargement border margin not behaving properly. so thought of getting an answer what is casing this in different print drivers

Comment: More recent versions of Excel seem to be buggy with rendering embedded controls. I sometimes have noticed similar problems when I have a spreadsheet hooked up to a projector. The buttons sometimes enlarge when clicked. Something is causing this sort of behavior, but one can only speculate about the cause.